Google Cloud Function's Firestore Queries Slow Down after user activity in
I have a Google Cloud Function (GCF) that queries Firestore. I also have an app that users read/write to Firestore. Before users use my app, the GCF works fine. After a few minutes of user activity, the queries in the GCF start to take a long time. For example, a simple update to a doc would take 27 seconds in the GCF.
Even a few minutes after user activity has stopped, the GCF's queries are still slow. Why is this?
code:
exports.processDocument = functions
  .runWith({ timeoutSeconds: 120 })
  .https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    const { documentId } = req.body;
    const id = req.body.documentId;

    if (!documentId) {
      return res.status(400).send("Missing documentId");
    }

    // Send a 200 response immediately
    res.status(200).send("Processing document...");

    const db = admin.firestore();
    const oneMindDocRef = db.collection("OneMind").doc(documentId);

    console.log(id, `Setting ${oneMindDocRef.id} document to being processed.`);
    await oneMindDocRef.update({
      processing: true,
      votingUsers: [],
    });
    console.log(id, `Set ${oneMindDocRef.id} document to being processed.`);

    const oneMindDoc = await oneMindDocRef.get();
    console.log(id, "Got OneMind document data");

    const activeUsers = oneMindDoc.data().activeUsers;
    const roundNumber = oneMindDoc.data().roundNumber;
    console.log(id, "Got activeUsers and roundNumber");

    if (!activeUsers || activeUsers.length === 0) {
      console.log(
        id,
        `No active users. Resetting ${oneMindDocRef.id} document.`
      );
      await oneMindDocRef.update({
        lastUpdated: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
        processing: false,
        activeUsersCount: 0,
        activeUsers: [],
      });
      console.log(id, `${oneMindDocRef.id} document reset.`);

      console.log(`Document ${oneMindDocRef.id} reset due to no active users.`);
      return;
    }
    const proposedMessagesRef = db.collection("proposedMessages");

    if (oneMindDoc.data().userFeedbackMechanism == "slider") {
      await calculateWeightedAverageScores(db, documentId);
    }

    const proposedMessagesDocs = await proposedMessagesRef
      .where("roundNumber", "==", roundNumber)
      .where("chatroomName", "==", oneMindDoc.data().chatroomName)
      .orderBy("votes", "desc")
      .orderBy("creation", "asc")
      .get();

    console.log(id, "Got all proposed messages for the current round.");
    if (proposedMessagesDocs.docs.length === 0) {
      await oneMindDocRef.update({
        activeUsers: [],
        activeUsersCount: 0,
        lastUpdated: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
        processing: false,
      });
      console.log(
        id,
        `${oneMindDocRef.id} document reset due to no proposed messages.`
      );

      console.log(
        `Document ${oneMindDocRef.id} reset due to no proposed messages.`
      );
      return;
    }

    const highestVotedMessageDoc = proposedMessagesDocs.docs[0];
    const highestVotedMessageData = highestVotedMessageDoc.data();

    console.log(id, 'Adding winning message to "messages" collection');
    const {
      message,
      creation,
      translatedText,
      creator,
      imageUrl,
      chatroomName,
      speaker,
    } = highestVotedMessageData;

    const messageRef = db.collection("messages").doc();
    const messageData = {
      creation: creation,
      creator: creator,
      speaker: speaker,
      roundNumber: roundNumber,
    };
    console.log("New message doc id: ", messageRef.id);

    if (imageUrl) {
      messageData.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    if (message) {
      messageData.message = message;
    }

    if (translatedText) {
      messageData.translatedText = translatedText;
    }

    if (chatroomName) {
      messageData.chatroomName = chatroomName;
    }

    await messageRef.set(messageData);
    console.log(id, "New document created in messages collection.");

    let newCurrentSpeaker = oneMindDoc.data().currentSpeaker;
    if (oneMindDoc.data().chatroomName !== "OneMind") {
      newCurrentSpeaker =
        newCurrentSpeaker === oneMindDoc.data().team1
          ? oneMindDoc.data().team2
          : oneMindDoc.data().team1;
      console.log(
        `Updating current speaker from ${
          oneMindDoc.data().currentSpeaker
        } to ${newCurrentSpeaker}`
      );
    }

    console.log(id, `Resetting ${oneMindDocRef.id} document for next message`);
    await oneMindDocRef.update({
      activeUsers: [],
      activeUsersCount: 0,
      lastUpdated: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      processing: false,
      currentSpeaker: newCurrentSpeaker,
      roundNumber: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1),
    });
    console.log(id, `${oneMindDocRef.id} document reset.`);
  });

logs:
2024-10-10 18:31:05.099 EDT processDocument4873x1mfdaij Function execution started
2024-10-10 18:31:05.256 EDT processDocument4873x1mfdaij about to start waiting
2024-10-10 18:31:05.257 EDT processDocument4873x1mfdaij done waiting
2024-10-10 18:31:05.257 EDT processDocument4873x1mfdaij Function execution took 157 ms, finished with status code: 200
2024-10-10 18:31:05.257 EDT processDocument4873x1mfdaij OneMind Setting OneMind document to being processed.
2024-10-10 18:31:07.955 EDT processDocument4873x1mfdaij OneMind Set OneMind document to being processed.
2024-10-10 18:31:34.255 EDT processDocument4873x1mfdaij OneMind Got OneMind document data
2024-10-10 18:31:41.855 EDT processDocument4873x1mfdaij OneMind Got activeUsers and roundNumber
2024-10-10 18:31:41.855 EDT processDocument4873x1mfdaij OneMind No active users. Resetting OneMind document.
2024-10-10 18:31:51.860 EDT processDocument4873x1mfdaij OneMind OneMind document reset.
2024-10-10 18:31:51.860 EDT processDocument4873x1mfdaij Document OneMind reset due to no active users.

Notice how the last two lines of code are 27 seconds apart, but all that happened in between is that I updated a document in Firestore.

Without seeing your code and understanding how you benchmark it, there's not much we can do to help.  Please edit your question with code and instructions on how to reproduce the issue so we can see if you might be doing something wrong.  Cloud Functions and Firestore don't just slow down under light load.

@DougStevenson updated

Your onRequest function doesn't send a response to the caller.  How is this an actual useful function that terminates normally?

@DougStevenson I removed it for simplicity purposes, the actual function is quite involved. These are some of the first few lines of the function

You should provide code that you've actually run and benchmarked, not some redacted code.  We should be able to take your code and instructions to run it to reproduce the issue.

The problem is that you're sending a response before all of the work completes.  Cloud Functions doesn't support performing "background" work after the response is complete.  Sending the response effectively terminates the function:

By terminating functions correctly, you can avoid excessive charges from functions that run for too long or loop infinitely. Also, you can make sure that the Cloud Functions instance running your function does not shut down before your function successfully reaches its terminating condition or state.
Terminate HTTP functions with res.redirect(), res.send(), or res.end().

In fact, you can expect that any "dangling" work that doesn't complete before the response is sent will behave erratically or not at all.
In order to implement this function correctly, you should wait for all the work the complete before sending the final response.  That means you need to put this at the end after all other promises have been awaited: res.status(200).send("Processing document...");
If you must absolutely end the HTTP function immediately, then you can't do the work inside the function at all.  Instead, you would have to perhaps write a separate pubsub function and send it a message from your HTTP function with a description of the work to do.
